# The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object '....'

Tags: c#, odbc, paradox

I have a folder containing a few paradox 5 files.

_folder = @"c:\temp\resource";

I then use the connection string

ConnectionString: Driver={Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )};DriverID=538;Fil=Paradox 5.X;DefaultDir=c:\temp\resource;Dbq=c:\temp\resource;CollatingSequence=ASCII;

Access the files.

```
    [Test]
    public void Paradoxgroupsales()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = GetDataSetFromAdapter(ds, _connectionString, "SELECT * FROM groupsales");
        foreach (String s in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }

public DataSet GetDataSetFromAdapter(DataSet dataSet, string connectionString, string queryString)
    {
        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            connection.Close();
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
```

When I run the code I keep getting the following errors

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Paradox Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'groupsales'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

I know that the file exists and that it is reading from the right path because I have a paradox 4 file in the same folder and when I select from it the error is

```
External table is not in the expected format.
```

As I would expect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Like ironic said in the answer the table doesn't exists. You have another problem???

Answer (score 1):

A I can understand from your post, there is no problem.

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR
>   [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Paradox
>   Driver] The Microsoft Jet database
>   engine could not find the object
>   'groupsales'

means that there is no table 'groupsales'

Comment: to be more exact: no table, stored procedure, view or any other object from which you can select

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the file name doesn't meet the MS-DOS 8.3 standards:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209685

Make sure the file name of the table does not exceed 8 character for the name and 3 for the extension.

Comment: The 8.3 is a starting point, but I have my files as 8.3 and it keeps saying that "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object ..."